# Git add remote, is the ssh:// prefix required

Tags: git, ssh

When adding a git repo as a remote is the ssh:// prefix required? I see it all the time simply as:

```
git remote add user@server.com/path/here
```

Is the ssh:// prefix implied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git defaults to ssh protocol in the event no other is specified.

See

http://book.git-scm.com/3_getting_a_git_repository.html

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior. If I use ssh:// I can push, if I don't supply it, I am getting: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Try doing git remote add user@server.com:/path/here (note the : between server and path)

Answer (score 1):

Git assumes SSH if you aren’t explicit

my source:
http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html

Answer (score 1):

Good question. It's a shorthand way of doing ssh but it's syntax is different than using SSH url protocol. Using the common shorthand above, for example, there's no space to specify a port (22 is assumed and most common anyways).

See my blog post for more examples of the various ways you can specify including using .ssh/config file:
http://readystate4.com/2011/03/30/working-with-git-repos-on-non-standard-ports/